# Changing the value of String.xml

Tags: java, android

This Might be a stupid question but please forgive me as I am only a learner.

Is it possible to change the value of player in a method from class if so, please tell me how.

**This is part of my R.java**

```
    public static final class string {
    public static final int player=0x7f060003;
```

**This is part of my string.xml from values file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="player">player</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: If you need to change why use it in first instance? It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: thank you for responding but I need it in values as I want to use it in my layouts.

Comment: ok.. and why you need to change it?

Comment: I want it so you can change player's name every time you open the application(like doodle jump)

Comment: before starting programming on Android platform you should read Guide on d.android.com .... anyway look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: but how do you get the player's name?

Comment: ok thank you I will do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant change android application resources in any way. All resources are read only. Maybe you can use SharedPreferences. You can read initial value from resources and then use SharedPreferences to store actual value which you can modify.

Comment: is it possible to have something like a viable which can be on xml and java?

Comment: Thank you but it seems to be very complicated I don't think I would be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change anything in R.java. Don't even try to. You are just asking for a lot of bugs if u do.
If u want to change the title and you are using an ActionBar, you can use the setTitle("String"); method.

Inside the method of a class, u need:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar ab= getActionBar();   //Creates new ActionBar Instance Object
    ab.setTitle("Welcome to my App!"); //Sets the title of that ActionBar Object
}

//Method that inflates the ActionBar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_action_bar, Menu);
    return true;
}
```

Another way u can change the title is if u put a TextView on top of your layout and change what shows up in the TextView.